# Object Expected in asp.net IE 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This code was given to me. Last time, this was working. But now it throws an Object Expected error. I'm new to javascript so I don't know what went wrong or how to fix it. Can someone help me? The flow of the code is when the user click the Edit link in the gridview, it changes into Update Cancel. Then the gridview will now be editable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(':checkbox').change(function () {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).val('1');
      } else {
        $(this).val('0');
      }
    });

    $("[id^=txtNumberVal]").bind("keypress", function (e) {
      var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
      var chars = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
      var intRegex = '[-+]?([0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)';
      if (!chars.match(intRegex)) {
        alert('Please enter a valid number');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });

  function editClick(i, e, v) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var id = 0;
      $("#<%=dgRule.ClientID%> tr").each(function () {
        id = $(this).find("td:eq(5) input[type=hidden]").val();
        $("#Edit" + id).show();
        $("#Update" + id).hide();
        $("#Cancel" + id).hide();

        if ((i == id) && (e == "E")) {
          if (v == "1") {
            $("#numberVal" + id).hide();
            $("#txtNumberVal" + id).show();
          } else if (v == "2") {
            $("#chkBoolVal" + id).removeAttr('disabled');
          } else if (v == "4") {
            $("#charVal" + id).hide();
            $("#txtCharVal" + id).show();
          }
        } else {
          $("#numberVal" + id).show();
          $("#txtNumberVal" + id).hide();
          $("#chkBoolVal" + id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          $("#charVal" + id).show();
          $("#txtCharVal" + id).hide();
        }

      });
    });

    if (e == "U") {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "EditPasswordRule.aspx/UpdatePwdRule",
        data: "{ numberVal: '" + $("#txtNumberVal" + i).val() + "', boolVal: '" + $("#chkBoolVal" + i).val() + "', charVal: '" + $("#txtCharVal" + i).val() + "', ruleID: '" + i + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
          if ((result.d).indexOf("Failed")) {
            $("#numberVal" + i).text(parseFloat($("#hdNumberVal" + i).val()).toFixed(2));
          }
          else {
            $("#numberVal" + i).text(parseFloat($("#txtNumberVal" + i).val()).toFixed(2));
          }
          $("#charVal" + i).text($("#txtCharVal" + i).val());
          alert(result.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
          alert(error);
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
    else if (e == "E") {
      $("#txtNumberVal" + i).val(parseFloat($("#numberVal" + i).text()).toFixed(2));
      $("#txtCharVal" + i).val($("#charVal" + i).text());
      if ($("#chkBoolVal" + i).is(":checked")) {
        $("#boolVal" + i).val('1');
      } else {
        $("#boolVal" + i).val('0');
      }
      $("#Edit" + i).hide();
      $("#Update" + i).show();
      $("#Cancel" + i).show();
    } else if (e == "C") {
      if ($("#boolVal" + i).val() == "1") {
        $("#chkBoolVal" + i).prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        $("#chkBoolVal" + i).prop('checked', false);
      }
      $("#Edit" + i).show();
      $("#Update" + i).hide();
      $("#Cancel" + i).hide();
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: You should provide the line where the error occurs if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open the developer tool (F12) and go to the console window, you get the same error in console log too, double clicking on the error will lead you to the line which causing the error. This error something like "object reference not set to instance of an object" error in .net. :)

good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out the path of the javascripts needed is not in the right direction because it lacks ../